# If Narayana is father of Kaama, then why should we disregard lust, sex, et cetera?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, sex, kamadeva

Krishna is also called KandarpaJanaka, meaning the father of Kaama. Moreover Kaama Himself is a God. So why are we constantly told to shun lust, sexual desires et cetera.

Please note, that I am not seeking for an approval from our Scriptures that - "go have sexual courses". I just want to know why should we disregard it. Why should we look at it as a bad thing. Can we not have equal vision?

If I should disregard Kaama, why should I not disregard compassion, mercy, helpfulness et cetera also?

Comment: Dharma ,Artha ,KAMA & Moksha are four pillers of Hinduism. It forbids  overindulgence of Materialist activities through pleasure sences.Sanyasis are advised to keep away from material pleasurs.Grihastha should use Kama sensibly.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Better to avoid honorifics on this forum. FYI: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/250

Comment: not part of this question but by the way shree krisna is only father of Kaama due to the curse of brahma, lord brahma cursed kaamdev to burn by lord Rudra, later on kama explained him that it is not his fault then brahma told him that you will be born to krishna to get back ur body.

Comment: Kama means just desire, it can be good desire of seeking god or it can be sexual desire also.. Not all Kama are good. Its like whatever desire which makes you turn more towards God is good for one as it  eventually lead us to moksha. Whatever desire which turns one away from God is bad desire because it makes one further away from moksha. Sexual desire it turns away from god.. because of its potential to overindulgence and losing ones virya which is needed for good health, mind and peace..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We are not asked to shun Kama.
Dharma, Artha, Kama, Moksha - are the 4 purusharthas.
 **As long as it follows the rules of Dharma**, it is completely acceptable.

But since Kama is so powerful that it can make us ignore the rules of Dharma, we are asked to be very careful with it, just like we are told not to play with fire but keep a safe distance from it.
Kama includes all sensory enjoyment (hearing, touching, seeing, tasting, smelling), not just lust.

[The senses are strong like horses, they can drag away even a man of intelligence if not under control - Bhagavad Gita](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-6-34/).

Comment: @SwiftPushkar does he mean - http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-LgksKTHCY7E/UQ5bTrM-M9I/AAAAAAAAAGQ/Qc1QtAdC4Bs/s1600/Arjunas-Chariot.jpg

Comment: @AnuragSingh, yes that image appropriately shows how out-of-control horses (senses) can lead a man astray