# Why do people choose ascetism?

Tags: moksha, kama

Ascetics have to deny themselves worldly pleasures, yet "kama" and pleasure is also seen as fundamental in the cycle of Hindu life. Why are there two separate paths to the same Moksha?

Comment: they deny AFTER enjoying. sanyasa is the last stage of life. there is only 1 path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If Narayana is father of Kaama, then why should we disregard lust, sex, et cetera?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18267/if-narayana-is-father-of-kaama-then-why-should-we-disregard-lust-sex-et-ceter)